# How is sin transfered from one to another?

Tags: sin

Question : How is sin transferred from person to another person? Not through birth?

We can not accuse Adam when we see him that he caused all humanities sin. Why because the word says "we all have sinned and have gone astray". We all sin sometime between our birth and death, yes we are the ones that sin (its our sin not anyone's else sin that made us a sinner). Therefore Jesus came to save the world from sin, yes yours and mine ( the sins we individually sinned).

Through one mans sin we all have sinned, not one righteous (through one mans righteousness we are all righteous ).

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately, this question isn't a good fit for this site: we don't attempt to discover the truth, *per se*, but rather our goal is to objectively describe and learn what specific groups of Christians believe. If you'd like to narrow the question by asking for the biblical basis for a particular view, or for the view of a particular tradition, this question may be answerable.  When you get a chance, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: This sounds more like a statement than a question. Is there something you actually wanted to ask? Or did you just want to make a doctrinal point?

Answer (score 2):

Original sin is a lack of infused Grace, with infused Grace being a partaking of the Divine Nature (2 Peter 1:4).

Original sin isn't a thing, it is a lack of a thing. Adam didn't pass anything on, he didn't pass on something he lost.

One of the effects or qualities of this original Grace is it kept the emotional and physical side of man (the flesh, see Gallatians 5) subordinate to the rational and spiritual side (the spirit). When the Grace was lost through sin, it caused the flesh to struggle with the  spirit for control of a man (I want (the flesh) to eat the cake, but I know (the spirit) I shouldn't). When the spirit of man rebelled against God, his flesh rebelled against his spirit.

Jesus came to offer this gift of Grace to us, although it doesn't immediately correct the internal discord within us.

Christi pax,

Lucretius

Comment: This is excellent, I wonder if clarifications between persons and Nature would help the undicipled understand this more clearly.  I fear it will be closed because The OP does not direct itself towards a single faith practice, sadly, he will more likely then not never return to this site.

Comment: I've never look at this in this light before. Very insightful! Dominus vobiscum!